# List view does not update at all

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Hi i am using view pager indicator with three fragments and in one of the i have a list view that show the content of my SQLite Database but when a add data to my table the list view doesn't show he new data that i have added here is my code:

```
public class caleryhistory extends SherlockListFragment {
    List<calery_lagari> Calery_lagari;
    calery_lagari_SQLiteData data;
    ArrayAdapter<calery_lagari> adapter;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calery_history, null);


        data = new calery_lagari_SQLiteData(getActivity());
        data.open();
        Calery_lagari = data.findall();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<calery_lagari>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.listback_layout, Calery_lagari);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return v;

    }
```

so any help?
Thanks in advance! :)

**Update**

```
import java.util.List;

import mr.chag.va.lagar.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;


public class caleryhistory extends SherlockListFragment {
    List<calery_lagari> Calery_lagari;
    calery_lagari_SQLiteData data;
    ArrayAdapter<calery_lagari> adapter;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calery_history, null);




        return v;

    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        data = new calery_lagari_SQLiteData(getActivity());
        data.open();
        Calery_lagari = data.findall();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<calery_lagari>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.listback_layout, Calery_lagari);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         ListView listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
         listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="clear"
        android:text="clear all" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way when extending `SherlockListFragments` is to have `onCreateView` return the  the inflated view, then override `onViewCreated`. And put your code that changes your view in there.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle b){
     return inflater.inflate(R.layout.calery_history, null);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
     data = new calery_lagari_SQLiteData(getActivity());
     data.open();
     Calery_lagari = data.findall();
     adapter = new ArrayAdapter<calery_lagari>(getActivity(), view.R.layout.listback_layout, Calery_lagari);
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

     setListAdapter(adapter);

     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: It should... What is it doing now?

Comment: i have brought all of my code to onViewCreated Override but still the list view is not updating it just shows the old data :(

Comment: How was the old data populated? If this code isn't working, it SHOULD show an empty list.

Comment: Maybe your problem isn't with your fragments, but your adapter. Post that code

Comment: i have an other fragment that adds data to my table with some edit texts and i need to show those data in this fragment. for example when i add a data in my second fragment and i scroll to the first fragment (this fragment) i cant see the data i have added but when restart m app i can see the new data

Comment: i am using the android stock array adapter. will creating a custom adapter solve the problem?

Comment: No. It should work fine. Try putting a log in there, and see if your actually retrieving information

Answer (score 1):

First problem is that you set adapter in onCreateView. In onCreateView list view is not created yet. Second you need to set adapter to correct list view. Because you override oncreateview you can't use setListAdapter because it's referring to list view from default viet. Try this:

```
       @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.calery_history, null);
}

    @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    data = new calery_lagari_SQLiteData(getActivity());
    data.open();
    Calery_lagari = data.findall();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<calery_lagari>(getActivity(),
            view.R.layout.listback_layout, Calery_lagari);

    ListView listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_LISTVIEW_ID);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your attention i have updated the question

Comment: Try to extend SherlockFragment instead of SherlockListFragment

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `setListAdapter` at this point, as the view is not yet set.

You need to wait until `onViewCreated`.